# Amazon PHP SDK Latest Exception Handling

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am creating a service using Amazon SNS and I am stuck at exception handling with the latest SDK. Basically I am not sure how to know the specific details of an exception thrown: For example, the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sns-2010-03-31.html#publish) says that when a notification is published (eg. `$snsClient->publish(...);`), it throws errors like:

- `InvalidParameterException`
- `InvalidParameterValueException`
- `InternalErrorException`
- `NotFoundException`
- `EndpointDisabledException`
- `PlatformApplicationDisabledException`
- `AuthorizationErrorException`

However there are no real classes like these in the SDK. I suppose the `publish()` method would throw an `Aws\Sns\Exception\SnsException`.  I'd like specifically know how to grab `EndpointDisabledException` and `NotFoundException`. Am I missing anything in the documentation?

Comment: Are you sure "there are no real classes like these in the SDK"? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Sns.Exception.EndpointDisabledException.html

Comment: I did mention I am using the latest SDK. There are no concrete exception classes in the latest SDK (2010-03-31). Anyways I figured out the solution. Let me give you a kudo for the response.